# How to detect when scroll is at the bottom of list in Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I wonder if Onsen UI list has something to do with detecting when the scroller reach bottom of the list.

Comment: There is nothing built-in for that. You need Javascript or AngularJS directives to do it.

Comment: Hi rafita, right now do u have any idea to do it?